# How to use a static member in UDF that is called by query?

Tags: vba, ms-access, static-members

I have a query where one of the values is returned by a UDF:

```
select name,coord,convertCoord(coord) from testTable;
```

`convertCoord()` uses `Regex` and `MatchCollection` objects to return its value:

```
Dim re As New RegExp
Dim mtch As Match
Dim matches As MatchCollection

Function convertCoord(str As String) As String

re.Pattern = "(find|this)pattern"
Set matches = re.Execute(str)
If matches.Count > 0 Then
    Set mtch = matches(1)
    convertCoord = mtch.Value
Else
    convertCoord = ""
End If

End Function
```

I'm trying to speed up the query, and I'm wondering if there's a way to make one instance of `re`,`mtch`, and `matches` that can be referred to by every call to `convertCoord()`.  If I understand correctly, every result row in the query calls `convertCoord()`, which constructs and destructs all the objects repeatedly, and all this object creation slows down the query.

Or are they already static, and therefore only constructed once, because I've declared them outside of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Static` key word when you declare your `RegExp`.  However, you can only use it within a procedure (function or subroutine).  If you try to use it for a module-level variable, it triggers a compiler error.

I don't think you need to declare *mtch* and *matches* as `Static` because you don't want to preserve their values from one function call to the next.  I also don't see why they should be module-level variables, so I made them local to the function.

```vb
Function convertCoord(str As String) As String
Static re As RegExp
Dim mtch As Match
Dim matches As MatchCollection

If re Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "RegExp Is Nothing"
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.pattern = "(find|this)pattern"
Else
    Debug.Print "RegExp active"
End If

' insert code which uses the RegExp

End Function
```

Test a similar function with your query.  After you confirm it prints *"RegExp Is Nothing"* no more than once, you'll likely want to discard the `Debug.Print` statements.  :-)